# What's the difference between Media and Press

Tags: differences, synonyms

What's the difference between Media  and Press, I think that press for newspapers and media for TV, can anyone give us details about that?

Comment: Also see [*"Today we say media instead of “the press.” But it’s a mistake. The press has.."*](http://pressthink.org/about/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These days, "press" would have a strong traditional-media connotation, likely excluding bloggers, since new-media publishers neither own nor use industrial printing equipment.  "Media" would include basically anyone who writes or speaks for an audience.

Comment: So you're saying Internet-based news outlets are not part of the media?

Comment: "'Media' would include basically anyone who writes or speaks for an audience." That sounds like it would include Internet-based news outlets.

Answer (score 7):

"The press" is used to describe both reporters and news outlets or media. It would make sense that "the press," at some point, referred exclusively to reporters for paper-based news media (because they're produced using printing presses) and also to that news medium itself, but it seems to be used for reporters representing any news media nowadays, as well as for the media.

To throw a little grammar into the mix, "media" is plural and refers to all the news media: magazine, newspaper, Internet, TV, radio, etc. Each of those is a news "medium." To me, that's the more interesting part.

So, to summarize, "the press" is typically used to refer to the people who gather the news, but can also refer to news outlets. News "media" are ways of distributing news.

Answer (score 3):

The "media" also encompasses things that are not news related. Phenomenon and the people involved in them that are purely entertainment are also part of the "media"

Answer (score 0):

from yahoo answer:
"Press" generally refers to print media (i.e. off the printing press) like newspapers and magazines. "Media" is a broader term that includes TV, radio, Internet etc. People often use them interchangeably though especially as we get more and more media conglomerates that own newspapers and other "non-press" media as well - most newspapers now have online editions including videos, etc. As many people no longer get their news from newspapers, the term "press" will probably migrate to mean all major media sources.

Answer (score 0):

Possible definiton:

1. Press - subset of media chiefly dealing in written words (e.g., Stack Overflow)
2. Media - all mediums of expression - audio, video, sensory

Answer (score 0):

**MEDIA:** A news media, that collects all the information around the world and establishes in the form of paper based (newspapers, magazines, books etc...) including basic grammar.

Comment: This response does not explain the difference between _media_ and _press_.

Comment: Also media is plural, printed newspapers are a news _medium_.

Answer (score -2):

so media is basically related to the internet or any medium through which we get information on various topics and can also be used for entertainment purposes. press is basically the group of ppl who do extensive research on various topics and and conduct various interviews such that the information found out by them is displayed on media .so media is basically a medium through which information is shared.